# How to treat methods which are only called by other methods from the same class but shouldn't be called by an instance?

Tags: java

I have the following situation:

```
public void method1()
{ 
    if(condition)
    {
        method2();

    }else
    {
        method3();
    }
}
```

method1() would be way too big, that's why I have split it into different methods.

Since method2() and method3() are only called by method1() it wouldn't make much sense if they would be visible outside the class.

My question: What is the proper design choice to make that happen ?

thank you

EDIT:

I've tried private and protected but the methods keep showing up.

e.g.:

```
Class class = new Class();

class.somePrivateOrProtectedMethod(Parameters...);
```

This is still possible.

Comment: Do you mean something other than making the methods private?

Comment: From your edit, are you trying to call the the method within the class it's declared in?

Comment: Yes. It is just a design-question because to me it doesn't feel right when you are able to call a method which is only used by another method.

Comment: What does "keep showing up" mean?

Comment: With showing up i mean: it is still possible to call that method with an instance of that class.

Comment: Only from within the class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare them as `private` instead of `public`:

```
private void method2() { ... }
```

This will have the effect that they are not visible to anything outside of the same file.

They will still be visible to code inside the same file, however, even if it is in a different class in the same file.

In Java, it is also always possible to call private methods on different instances (other than `this`) from within the same file. There is no way to restrict the visibility to the same *instance* (only to the same class/file).

Answer (score 2):

If your question is whether there exists a language construct in Java that restricts calling a method to a single other method, the answer is no.

You really shouldn't worry about that. You're the owner of the source code. As long as you encapsulate those methods correctly, with `private` as [Philipp pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002481/438154), then you're protected from the outside. You have no reason to protect yourself from the inside.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it might be possible by using nested Classes ? Or is this just overthinking ?

Comment: @SklogW You're overthinking it. It could not be done with nested classes either. `private` members of nested classes are still accessible to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that:

- your class is very large

(which means that)

- you find it difficult to keep track of the relationships between methods

(and therefore)

- you want to make it really clear in your code that `method2()` and `method3()` shouldn't be called from anywhere else that `method1()`

... then you could put those three methods  inside an inner class whose only purpose is to run `method1()`. All methods will still be accessible from the outer class, but the structure of the code will give a hint as to the expected usage.

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    private class ProcessDoer {

        public void doProcess() {
            if(condition) {
                method2();
            } else {
                method3();
            }
        }

        private void method2() {
            ...
        }

        private void method3() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However in a lot of situations that would be overkill.

Comment: I've just tried it. It indeed conveys the purpose of the methods but they are nevertheless accessible, only in this case it would be: Myclass class = new MyClass(); and then class.ProcessorDoer.method2(); But thanks for your answer.